What movie starts off at a theater in black and white?
Growing up, I watched a movie that starts off in black and white.  
Then, after a couple of minutes, credits roll, and it turns out that the movie is actually in color, but it was a group of people (I believe critics) watching a black and white movie at a theater.
I believe it is also a Christmas movie as well, and an older movie (at least 20 or so years old).  The movie was definitely in English, and PG (or G) rated.
I thought that it was Miracle on 34th Street, but I've watched the start of both the 1947 and the 1994 versions, and neither of them fit the bill.  I also considered It's a Wonderful Life, but it doesn't start off that way either.
What movie starts off as a black-and-white film at the theater?

Oz movies do that, no? Else maybe it's listed there: https://mubi.com/lists/films-in-both-color-and-black-and-white

Oz movies definitely don't start off in a theater.

Perhaps Purple Rose of Cairo (1985)

Set in New Jersey during the Great Depression in 1935, the film tells the story of Cecilia (Mia Farrow), a clumsy waitress who goes to the movies to escape her bleak life and loveless, abusive marriage to Monk (Danny Aiello), whom she has attempted to leave on numerous occasions.
The latest film Cecilia sees is a fictitious RKO Radio Pictures film, The Purple Rose of Cairo. It is the story of a rich Manhattan playwright named Henry (Edward Herrmann) who goes on an exotic vacation to Egypt with companions Jason (John Wood) and Rita (Deborah Rush). While in Egypt, the three meet archaeologist Tom Baxter (Jeff Daniels). Tom is brought back for a "madcap Manhattan weekend" where he falls head-over-heels for Kitty Haynes (Karen Akers), a chanteuse at the Copacabana.
After Cecilia sits through the film several times, Tom, noticing her, breaks the fourth wall, and emerges from the black-and-white screen into the colorful real world on the other side of the cinema's screen.
Wikipedia





Unfortunately, this isn't it.  That said...this looks really interesting.  I'll have to watch it.
